# Best solution to deploy geth(go-ethereum) on kubernetes(aws eks)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, go-ethereum, geth

I am trying to deploy geth on kubernetes.I need to have  all of my pods(2 currently) to have a common volume(persistent volume) mounted to the "/data/geth/chaindata" folder.i.e each pod reads and writes chaindata from a common volume. The requirement is mainly due to large size of chaindata folder.I  tried to mount chaindata folder of all three pods to a common persistent volume but got this error

> Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: resource temporarily unavailable

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ2Tc.png). I am also sharing the deployment file

[Deployment file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhANS.png).If each pod has different persistent volumes mounted then a lot of redundant disk space will be occupied. What can be an optimized solution to this?.Having different persistent volume for different pods is the only way ?

Comment: Hi @sahil, welcome to StackOverflow. A pice of advice: Do not post errors and/or code as an image (read this: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)). Please post the error and your deployment files as text.

Comment: Sure , i have edited it to have text wherever possible.